# How to manage specific and generic exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

What happens here if the OracleException here is not what I am looking for? Do I need to throw? Also catching a generic exception here is that the right thing to do?

```
try
{
    does some code
}
catch (OracleException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 20001)
    {
        throw new ValidationException("Unable blah blah blah");
    }
    throw;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log it
    TraceHelper.WriteLine("Exception updating tblah + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace, MessageCategory.Error);
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A really good thing to do is to realize when you have a bug in your code. How do you do that? Normally crashing or putting a global exception handler that traps Exceptions and informs the developer in some way.

Catching a generic exception and not throwing it goes against the previous statement so it is advised to not do it.

It is usually accepted as a good practice to fail fast ([here a description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast))

At last but not lease you normally do not want to catch an exception that you don't know how to recover from. What will you do in your application if you have a bug and you have an ArgumentNullException? There is nothing you can do in your code to recover from this situation, you must fail, inform de user and the developer and end the application.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you want to only catch the `OracleException` based on some condition of that exception. The good news is, with **C# 6.0** you can add a `when` clause to add that condition:

```
catch (OracleException ex) when (ex.Number == 20001) 
{ 
    throw new ValidationException("Unable blah blah blah");
}
```

This means that if `ex.Number` isn't 20001, the exception thrown will check the next catch clause you have, in this case, it will fall into your generic catch.

Whether or not the generic catch should be there is up to debate, as a ***general*** rule of thumb, you shouldn't have generic exception handling. If you don't know why the code is throwing the exception, how can you expect to handle it successfully?

Comment: Nice, so what happens if it isn't of type 20001? I guess that is what I'm not sure how to handle.

Comment: doesn't look im running 6.0 and not in a position to update it in the short term

Comment: In this case, is what I have accurate? I have a Global exception handler in my api which will pick up and show proper error handling to the front end.

Comment: _If you don't know why the code is throwing the exception, how can you expect to handle it successfully?_ +1 for this!